# Golang: Testing API using httptest returns 404

Tags: go, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to test a library I wrote that talks to an external API. I came up with this code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "net/url"
    "testing"
)

var (
    // mux is the HTTP request multiplexer used with the test server.
    mux *http.ServeMux

    // client is the GitHub client being tested.
    client *Client

    // server is a test HTTP server used to provide mock API responses.
    server *httptest.Server
)

func setup() {
    mux = http.NewServeMux()
    server = httptest.NewServer(mux)

    client = NewClient(nil, "foo")
    url, _ := url.Parse(server.URL)
    client.BaseURL = url

}

func teardown() {
    server.Close()
}

func testMethod(t *testing.T, r *http.Request, want string) {
    if got := r.Method; got != want {
        t.Errorf("Request method: %v, want %v", got, want)
    }
}

func TestSearchForInterest(t *testing.T) {
    setup()
    defer teardown()

    mux.HandleFunc("/topic/search?search-query=Clojure", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, `{"results": [ {"topic": "Clojure", "id": 1000} ]}`)
    })

    results, _, err := client.Topics.SearchForInterest("Clojure")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("SearchForInterest returned error: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(results)

}
```

When I run "go test" I keep getting an **error 404** not sure what I'm doing wrong. any pointers

Comment: I have never tried including a query string in the route, but that would be the first thing that jumps out to me as "highly suspicious"

Comment: I am assuming you are trying to test: https://github.com/johnwesonga/go-prismatic?  I would try to verify the test issue, but you have some compiler errors related to topic_tagurl based on Master HEAD.

Comment: The router you created doesn't have a route defined for "/topic/search?search-query=Clojure", so why would you expect anything but a 404?

Comment: sberry - fixed that bug in tagurl, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: sberry - yes the query string was the problem..thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the query param. that isn't a route.